# Answer that is a duplicate of the accepted answer should be deleted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, specific-question, deleted-answers

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502303/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-guid-of-an-application-in-net2-0), the original accepted answer was *wrong*, as in [*tragically wrong*](https://twitter.com/Foone/status/1229641258370355200).  Since [that answer was (At the time) the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/502323/revisions), the OP decided to copy and paste the *right* answer, according to their own words:

> Edit: To those who insist on downvoting... Unable to delete this answer because it is the accepted version. Therefore, am editing to include the correct answer ([JaredPar's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502303/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-guid-of-an-application-in-net2-0/502327#502327) below)

(Screenshot):
[image]

So, to recap:

1. User posts wrong answer.
2. Answer gets accepted.
3. User finds out answer is wrong; can't delete. Decides to copy and paste the right answer.
4. Answer gets unaccepted.
5. Internet finds out this is the wrong answer, gets a lot of traffic.

It's at this point that I flagged the answer with the following reason:

> Now that this answer has been unaccepted, copying and pasting the accepted answer into this answer is obsolete. This answer should be deleted as a duplicate answer (though it was done with the best of intentions). This twitter thread explains in more detail why it should be deleted: twitter.com/Foone/status/1229641258370355200 – George Stocker 23 hours ago

It was declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I probably wasn't as clear as I could be: I wasn't asking for it to be deleted because it was tragically wrong (even though it was), I was asking for it to be deleted because it's a *copy and paste of the accepted answer*.

My current request (and would like community input into this):

1. edit it out to say it's wrong and to point to the right answer (without copying the right answer)
2. Delete it, as is standard procedure for duplicate answers or plagiarized answers.

I prefer #2, as this is a copy and pasted answer, but as a high-reputation user, I cannot vote to delete positively scored answers, only a moderator can.

Comment: Tricky situation. Moderators should not get involved with judging the technical accuracy of answers. The answer isn't complete plagiarism, it contains original content, however wrong it may be; the duplicate part is just an artefact of the circumstances. We shouldn't generally bend any rules just because something is receiving more attention than the average post. — Overall, it'd be best for the author to delete it or the community to vote to delete this. Other than the fact that it's receiving some attention right now, there's nothing much there for a moderator to deal with.

Comment: @deceze note the screenshot, it’s positively scored so we can’t vote to delete it. Absent moderator intervention, we can’t do much.

Comment: Yes, so the only reason a moderator should get involved is that it's currently a popular post; is that reason enough to get on the slippery slope of deleting content we usually won't?

Comment: @deceze I’m a bit confused. We as moderators regularly deleted copy and pasted answers. Is there somewhere that changed?

Comment: The reason for that is typically *plagiarism*. I don't see a clear case of that here. The intent of the author clearly wasn't to plagiarise and they basically state that they're only doing so due to the circumstances (because they couldn't delete their post). — If anything, should we honour the poster's implied request for deletion…?

Comment: @deceze Isn't that what George has been asking for?

Comment: @yivi Trying to lawyer through this here; we don't want to be deleting for *the wrong reason*…

Comment: I have faced similar situations in the past too and it cannot be deleted or anything. It's quite annoying situation since the moderators tend to go to this one as you said: " flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies" all the time.

Answer (score 27):

Usually moderators would not get involved in wrong content. Plagiarism also wasn't a good reason to apply here, as the author's intent wasn't to plagiarise at all.

Of course, not removing this would be rather silly too, and would just end in it being voted into oblivion, and making Stack Overflow seem pretty foolish for insisting on keeping wrong content around for arbitrary reasons. So I've removed the answer, **on the basis that the author has implicitly requested deletion years ago.**

Comment: The bolded part is the important bit. It’s a silly limitation that accepted answers cannot be deleted even when the author wants to delete them and it’s obvious that they are not rage-quitting. This is where it makes sense for a moderator to step in.

Answer (score 17):

We don't have a way to unseat pinned, highly upvoted, but incorrect, accepted answers, after the asker has abdicated maintenance of the question, and this has caused [a lot of problems for users](https://twitter.com/Foone/status/1229641258370355200).

The situation:

1. User asks.
2. Another user answers carelessly.
3. Answer is accepted.
4. Another user answers carefully.
5. Asker ignores the new answer.
6. Sophisticated community generally accepts the new answer as the right one.
7. Unsophisticated users looking for a quick answer quickly upvote the top one.
8. The top answer continues to get upvotes because of its position.
9. The sophisticated community feels there is no recourse.

We need to remove the bad answer from being displayed front and center. There are several hypothetical ways of doing that that wouldn't involve a moderator:

- Unpin the answer. This should be easy - self-answers are already unpinned. But the answer may still have so many (misinformed) upvotes that it is still pinned at the top for most viewers.
- Delete the answer. A moderator can do this with a positively scored answer, but the community wants a way to do it in these situations without the mod. We always wanted these answers to stick around for posterity though, so if they were just unpinned, we could still accomplish that goal.
- Sophisticated editor adds a warning to the bad answer. We don't generally like these kinds of edits to answers, but they have become more acceptable as the need for them becomes more apparent. Other problems with this approach is that it can be done unilaterally by a single unsophisticated user (perhaps incorrectly), and if the answerer is uncooperative, they can simply roll-back the change.

I suggest we come up with a way of unpinning bad answers, and sorting answers so that better new answers rise to the top more quickly.

In this case, we have a cooperative initial answerer who has requested deletion, so we have sidestepped the issue once more. We will still continue to see more of these problems in the future.

I suggest we address this issue head-on right now before this happens again.

Comment: Even in the category of 'wrongness', this is a special case: this is tragically wrong with real world consequences. A situation where if high rep users could vote to delete positively scored answers, it'd be a matter of drawing attention to it; but in this case we can't. We can either edit the answer (to what? To leave its wrongness? To delete its wrongness?) or we can downvote, or we can flag. we can't clean up; and since Moderators are by design not subject matter experts, they won't clean it up when they see it unless we get lucky.

Comment: I say all that to say that fundamentally, we need to rethink how we handle wrongness over time.  The library has been created, now it's gotta be maintained; and that means fewer eyeballs because the answer has been around for so long. We're in the long tail of a few people seeing it, we have to have a plan for that.

Comment: @George I'm sure other wrongness on here has also had real world consequences. This one just happened to be widely publicised by someone competent who managed to track down the exact post that caused it. Popularity is the only thing that makes this post "special", not real-wordliness. Agreed though that we should have a better plan for this kind of case either way.

Comment: agreed. The original 'downvote wrong content' made sense in the beginning of an answer's lifecycle where there were a lot of views; but now we have very few visits to each question after it's been answered, causing (over time) bad answers to proliferate and lower the vaue of the site overall (and increase black-eyes).

Comment: One of the problems here is that once the answer is accepted owner cannot delete it.   It can be pretty frustrating experience.

Comment: This old Meta question is arguably related.  Just 20 days ago, it gained the tag [status-review]. [Keeping special status for Accepted Answers without sticking them to top forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268666/194264)

Answer (score 12):

The underlying problem here is that the acceptance mark prevented the answerer from removing their answer once they were notified that it was wrong. The answerer did actually want to remove it, but they were unable to and copied the correct answer as a workaround. I think it would be reasonable to argue that deleting the answer now would be acting on the answerer's intent, as they would have deleted it years ago if they had been able to.

The answer duplication is a side effect here, and maybe more of a distraction.

Answer (score 8):

As the purported 'antagonist' in question here, I think I have a right to clarify my point of view, although the Moderators, especially "@deceze" and "Mad scientist" have rightly guessed my intent.

I am especially chagrined at the assertion that it was a copy-paste of the correct answer or that plagiarism was either involved or even intended. I contend that this does not qualify as plagiarism and was not intended to be so. The basic characteristic of plagiarism is that you do not give credit where due, instead try to take it. The answer is not a duplicate as well, as is apparent to anyone.

1. The original answer was posted in Feb 2009 at a time when I was quite actively engaged in StackOverflow and was accepted by the OP immediately.
2. I was not an active member on the subsequent years and I returned in 2013 (4 years later) to find that this answer was getting several down-votes and discovered that the reason was because this answer was in fact, misleading. Since others could only point this out in comments and not everyone looking for a quick solution reads the comments, I decided to delete my post to prevent anyone using the incorrect code.
3. I tried deleting it but since it was still the accepted answer 4 years later, I could not delete it. I then decided to edit my answer to include **both a link to the correct answer as well a code correction along with comments**. I felt that would be sufficient to prevent anyone from being misled and that was my sole intention.
4. Again, in the subsequent years till now, I have not been a contributing member and only visit once in a while. Now, 11 years later, I am very surprised (if not perturbed) to find that this answer still is being debated and discussed.

As for the deletion, it is exactly what I had wanted and I thank the moderators for doing this... better late than never, I guess.

Comment: I apologize if it came across that I considered your answer 'plagiarized', I do not. I considered it a duplicate answer (which it was); but included the "standard procedure for duplicate answers or plagiarized answers" to accurately cite the procedure.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Thanks for the quick response. Apology accepted graciously. I appreciate and admire what you do for the community. Have a great one! :-)